# LDAP for Chef Server without Management Console UI

Tags: ldap, chef-infra, knife

Has anyone had success setting up LDAP users on chef server without the management console UI? I followed the setup here as if we had the management console https://docs.chef.io/server_ldap.html .

There does not seem to be any documentation for `knife create user` with an ldap setting(like is passed from the UI). Is there a way to setup ldap users without the management console ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a thing. LDAP is only useful for password-based logins, and password-based logins are only used by the web UI. So you can configure it, but it won't really do anything.

Comment: Thanks coderanger. That is a very clear explanation. I also ended up asking the chef slack yesterday, which is great as a resource